# How to convert a date into month in r platform using dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr

To convert the date into month, first i changed all the dates into one standard format using

```
list1<-as.Date(sample1$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

but this gave me NAs -

```
[1] "2015-06-24" "2015-06-23" "2015-06-25" "2015-06-26" "2015-06-30" "2015-06-29"
 [7] "2015-06-18" NA           "2015-06-27" "2015-06-15" "2015-06-13" "2015-06-17"
[13] "2015-06-22" "2015-06-16" "2015-06-19" NA           NA           "2015-05-26"
[19] "2015-06-28" NA           "2015-04-28" "2015-05-28" "2015-04-27" NA          
[25] NA           NA           NA           NA           "2015-04-13" "2015-04-24"
[31] "2015-04-30" NA           "2015-04-14" "2015-04-23" NA           "2015-04-22"
[37] "2015-04-29" "2015-04-17" NA           NA           NA           "2015-04-16"
[43] "2015-04-20" NA           "2015-05-21" "2015-05-27" "2015-06-14" "2015-05-16"
[49] "2015-06-20" "2015-04-25" "2015-05-14" "2015-05-20" NA           NA          
[55] NA           NA           "2015-05-18" "2015-05-22" "2015-05-29" NA          
[61] NA           NA           "2015-05-13" "2015-04-15" "2015-05-15" "2015-05-19"
[67] "2015-04-21" "2015-06-21" "2015-05-23" "2015-05-25" NA           NA          
[73] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           "2015-05-31"
[79] "2015-04-19" "2015-05-30" NA           "2015-04-18" "2015-04-26" "2015-05-17"
[85] "2015-05-24" NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
[91] NA
```

How do I convert all the dates to Date and then change into month using dplyr? I am very new to R. Please provide some explanation if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `dplyr`to change date formats:

Data:

```
dates <- c("2015-06-24", "2015-06-23", "2015-06-25")
```

Change format:

```
format(as.Date(dates, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Result:

```
[1] "06-24-2015" "06-23-2015" "06-25-2015"
```

If you do need `dplyr`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  dates = c("2015-06-24", "2015-06-23", "2015-06-25"))
```

Solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(date_new = format(as.Date(dates, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%m-%d-%Y"))
df
       dates   date_new
1 2015-06-24 06-24-2015
2 2015-06-23 06-23-2015
3 2015-06-25 06-25-2015
```